# SAS solve optimization problem for each row of a dataset

Tags: optimization, sas

I have a dataset like the following:

```
data have;
    id=1; x1=10; x2=3; x3=5; y=220;
    y1g=12; y2g=6; y3g=10;
    output;

    id=2; x1=7; x2=0; x3=3; y=100;
    y1g=12; y2g=0; y3g=10;
    output;
run;
```

for each record I want to had values for `y1`, `y2`, `y3`, such that

```
x1*y1+x2*y2+x3*y3=y
0=<y1<=12
0=<y2<=6
0=<y3<=10
```

I am not sure of which can be the objective function, but to fix the ideas

I might want that the solutions are as similar as possible to some initial guess, `y1g` ,`y2g`, `y3g`.
so for instance the objective might be:

`min (y1-y1g)**2+(y2-y2g)**2+(y3-y3g)**2`

I am using SAS9 M5 and have to apply the program to a dataset of about 100000 records.

can you suggest me with the proc optmodel code?
thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Although your solution is infeasible with your constraints, this is what the optmodel code looks like:

```
proc optmodel;
    set row;
    num id; 

    num x1{row};
    num x2{row};
    num x3{row};

    num y1g{row};
    num y2g{row};
    num y3g{row};
    num y{row};

    num y1sol{row};
    num y2sol{row};
    num y3sol{row};

    var y1;
    var y2;
    var y3;

    read data have into row=[id]
        x1 x2 x3 y y1g y2g y3g
    ;

    con con1: x1[id]*y1 + x2[id]*y2 + x3[id]*y3 = y[id];
    con con2: 0 <= y1 <= 12;
    con con3: 0 <= y2 <= 6;
    con con4: 0 <= y3 <= 10;

    min sum_squared_dif = ( (y1-y1g[id])**2+(y2-y2g[id])**2+(y3-y3g[id])**2 );
    
    cofor {i in row} do;
        id = i;

        solve;
        
        /* Save each individual solution */
        y1sol[id] = y1.sol;
        y2sol[id] = y2.sol;
        y3sol[id] = y3.sol;
    end;

    print y1sol y1g y2sol y2g y3sol y3g;
quit;
```

[image]

Note that the first row has an infeasible solution.